Why Gazebo simulation is not being updated from plugin?
I have the following plugin that tries to set a Material parameter with random values every two seconds. I can see in the terminal the values being different but I do not see those changes reflected on the GUI. What am I missing?
Here are the files that I am using:
plugin.cc
using namespace ros_gz_example_gazebo;

SatelliteGround::SatelliteGround(): gz::sim::System() {}

void SatelliteGround::Configure(
    const gz::sim::Entity &_entity,
    const std::shared_ptr<const sdf::Element> &_sdf,
    gz::sim::EntityComponentManager &_ecm,
    gz::sim::EventManager &_eventManager
)
{
    std::cout << "[PLUGIN] ID: " << _entity << ", Name: " << _ecm.Component<gz::sim::components::Name>(_entity)->Data() << std::endl;

    // auto groundPlaneModelEntity = _ecm.EntityByComponents(
    //     gz::sim::components::Name("ground_plane"),
    //     gz::sim::components::Model()
    // );
    // if (groundPlaneModelEntity)
    // {
    //     std::cout << "ground_plane model not found!" << std::endl;
    //     return;
    // }
    _ecm.Each<gz::sim::components::Name>(
        [&](const gz::sim::Entity &id, const gz::sim::components::Name *name) -> bool {
            std::cout << "Entity ID: " << id << ", Name: " << name->Data() << std::endl;
            return true; // Continue iteration
        }
    );

    this->groundPlaneVisualEntity =_ecm.EntityByComponents(
        gz::sim::components::Name("visual"),
        gz::sim::components::Visual()
    );
    if (!this->groundPlaneVisualEntity)
    {
        std::cout << "[PLUGIN] ground_plane visual not found!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}

void SatelliteGround::PreUpdate(
    const gz::sim::UpdateInfo &_info,
    gz::sim::EntityComponentManager &_ecm)
{
    this->simTime = _info.simTime;

    auto *materialComp = _ecm.Component<gz::sim::components::Material>(this->groundPlaneVisualEntity);
    if (!materialComp)
    {
        std::cout << "material component could not be found" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    
    if (this->simTime - this->lastUpdate < std::chrono::seconds(2))
        return;

    const gz::math::Color prevColor = materialComp->Data().Ambient();
    std::cout << "[PLUGIN] previous Color: " << prevColor << std::endl;

    sdf::Material newMaterial;
    newMaterial.SetAmbient(gz::math::Color(
        static_cast<float>(gz::math::Rand::DblUniform(0.0, 1.0)),
        static_cast<float>(gz::math::Rand::DblUniform(0.0, 1.0)),
        static_cast<float>(gz::math::Rand::DblUniform(0.0, 1.0))));
    materialComp->SetData(
        newMaterial,
        [](const sdf::Material &, const sdf::Material &){return false;}
    );

    _ecm.SetChanged(this->groundPlaneVisualEntity,
        gz::sim::components::Material::typeId,
        gz::sim::ComponentState::OneTimeChange);
    
    std::cout << "[PLUGIN] Color shoud have changed" << std::endl;

    this->lastUpdate = this->simTime;
}

plugin.hh
  class SatelliteGround:
    public gz::sim::System,
    public gz::sim::ISystemConfigure,
    public gz::sim::ISystemPreUpdate
  {
    public:
      SatelliteGround();
      void Configure(
        const gz::sim::Entity &_entity,
        const std::shared_ptr<const sdf::Element> &_sdf,
        gz::sim::EntityComponentManager &_ecm,
        gz::sim::EventManager &_eventManager
      ) override;
      
      void PreUpdate(
        const gz::sim::UpdateInfo &_info,
        gz::sim::EntityComponentManager &_ecm
      ) override;

    private:
      // void FindScene();
      // void PerformRenderingOperations();

      gz::sim::Entity groundPlaneVisualEntity{gz::sim::kNullEntity};
      // std::unique_ptr<SatelliteGroundPrivate> dataPtr;

      gz::common::ConnectionPtr connection{nullptr};
      std::chrono::steady_clock::duration simTime{0};
      std::chrono::steady_clock::duration lastUpdate{0};
      bool toggle{false};


      gz::transport::Node node;
      std::map<std::string, gz::sim::Entity> groundPlaneMap;
  };

vtol.sdf
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.7">
  <world name="vtol">
    <!-- <plugin filename="gz-sim-physics-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Physics">
    </plugin> -->
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-user-commands-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::UserCommands">
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
      <updateRate>25</updateRate>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-imu-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Imu">
    </plugin>
    <!-- So camera can be used -->
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-sensors-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Sensors">
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>
    
    <light type="directional" name="sun">
      <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
      <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
      <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <constant>0.9</constant>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
    </light>

    <model name="ground_plane">
      <plugin
        filename="SatelliteGround"
        name="ros_gz_example_gazebo::SatelliteGround">
      </plugin>
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>20 20 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>20 20 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>

    <!-- Load the scenario -->
    <!-- <include>
      <uri>model://runway</uri>
    </include> -->
    <!-- <include>
      <uri>package://ros_gz_example_description/models/satellite_ground</uri>
    </include> -->

    <include>
      <pose degrees="true">0 0 5 0 0 0</pose>
      <uri>package://ros_gz_example_description/models/vtol</uri>
    </include>

  </world>
</sdf>

